# Selecting all the data using time greater than 4pm

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to select the Data containing time > 4pm in `datatimestamp` every day in SQL Server Management Studio Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4060.00 (X64)   DB table which has two years of data. What's the best way to do this? My time stamp has following format:`DATETIME, '2005-10-13 16:00:00', 102`.  I have data at random times every afternoon. I need to get the data after 4pm for every day. Not just for one day.

For example i tried for one day like this:

```
SELECT     Yield, Date, ProductType, Direct
FROM         MIAC_CCYX
WHERE     (Date < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2005-10-13 16:00:00', 102))  Thanks for help
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something else?  Is your time stamp actually a `timestamp` data type, a `datetime`, or something else?

Comment: what is 102 in your question ? will it not be 2005-10-13 16:00:00.102 ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's hard to read your question, but assuming you really are using a `datetime` data type, you can use [`datepart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to find any dates with a time greater than 4 PM:

```
WHERE datepart(hh, YourDate) > 16
```

Since you now need minutes as well, if you want records after 4:45 PM, you can cast your date to a time like this:

**SQL Server 2000/2005**

```
SELECT Yield, [Date], ProductType, Direct 
FROM MIAC_CCYX 
WHERE cast(convert(char(8), [Date], 108) as datetime) > cast('16:45' as datetime)
```

Essentially you cast the date using [`convert`'s Date and Time styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to convert the date to a time string, then convert back to a `datetime` for comparison against your desired time.

**SQL Server 2008+**

```
SELECT Yield, [Date], ProductType, Direct 
FROM MIAC_CCYX 
WHERE CAST([Date] as time) > CAST('16:45' as time)
```

Comment: Okay, what is the data type of your field you are querying against? Is it a `timestamp`, `datetime`, `varchar` or something else?  What is the exact conversion error you are getting?  You're giving us next to nothing to work with.

Comment: Have you explicitly tried `SELECT Yield, [Date], ProductType, Direct FROM MIAC_CCYX WHERE datepart(hh, [Date]) > 16`?

Comment: datepart(hh, [Date]) > 16 works, Thank You. but i also need minutes. My time should be 4:45, then how should i go about it

Comment: I tried WHERE CAST([Date] as time) > CAST('16:45' as time). The error was type time is not a system defined type

Comment: You're correct; I forgot `time` wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2008; updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will work whatever your date is. This will not compare the dates. Rather, Datepart() will extract the hour element from datetime and comapre with your given time (e.g. 4 P.M. in your case)

```
SELECT * from <table> where DATEPART(hh, ModifiedDate) >= 16
```

I am assuming ModifiedDate as column name. this will return data from 4 P.M. to 11:59:59 P.M
Edit: I have checked this against MS SQL server 2012. Also it will work with datetime format.

Comment: What's the point of using `GETDATE()`? By using `GETDATE()`, that will select everything from the table if you happen to run the query after 4 PM. If you run it before 4 PM, you'll get nothing.

Comment: This will be used to get current day's data. to get data for all previous days, user can enter the date. This is not a big deal....

Comment: No, it won't. You are selecting everything if the current hour in `getdate()` is greater than 16.  You're not even specifying a table column in your `WHERE` staetment.  Try running `SELECT * from <table> where DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) > 23` and see what you get (assuming it isn't past 11 PM where you are).

Comment: I have tried DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) > 23, it didn't get any row

Comment: thanks @LittleBobbyTables, got your point. I have updated my cmd.